# AppleScript App entitlement for access-group identifier="*"

Tags: xcode, macos, applescript

I am developing a Mac app that makes use of App Scripting. The is Sandboxed and thus needs the proper entitlements in order to get permissions to send AppleScript events to other apps. I have gotten this working properly for apps (like Mail and spotify) which specify access-group identifiers like this:

```
<access-group identifier="com.apple.mail.compose" access="rw"/>
<access-group identifier="com.spotify.playback"/>
```

However, a few other of the Apple made apps (like Xcode) specify their identifiers like this:

```
<access-group identifier="*"/>
```

I have tried to configure my entitlement file like this:

```
<key>com.apple.security.scripting-targets</key>
<dict>
    <key>com.apple.dt.Xcode</key>
    <array>
        <string>*</string>
    </array>
</dict>
```

, but when doing this it does not work and I get this error message in the console:

```
AppleEvents/sandbox: Returning errAEPrivilegeError/-10004 and denying dispatch of event xcod/buld from process '-------'/0x0-0x1a05a04, pid=82514, because it is not entitled to send an AppleEvent to this process.
```

Does anyone know how to properly configure this?

Answer (score 0):

Actually I found the answer myself. In the sdef Man pages it states:

> An identifier of "*" means the element is usable by any application,
>   without an explicit entitlement.

This means that you do not have to add the identifiers in your entitlements file and it should work regardless. The reason why I got the error was because I accidentally used commands that were not included in those particular access-groups.